# Revit Activate 3D View using Revit API 2014

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, revit

I have opened a revit document using Revit API 2014 from within Idling event handler. After that I am trying to activate 3D view but I am getting some exception (Setting active view is temporarily disabled). Is there any way to get around this exception?. Please refer the code below and the journal output. Thanks.

**Note: Modelless dialog activates 3D view without any problem.**

Code Snippet to activate 3D View:

```
Document doc = uiApp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
ElementClassFilter viewFilter = new ElementClassFilter(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.View3D));
viewCollector.WherePasses(viewFilter);

try
{
   foreach (Autodesk.Revit.DB.View3D vw in viewCollector)
   {
      if (vw.IsValidObject && !vw.IsTemplate)
      {
            uiApp.ActiveUIDocument.ActiveView = vw;
            break;
       }
    }
}  

catch (Exception e)
{
      throw e;
}
finally
{
      viewCollector.Dispose();
      viewFilter.Dispose();
}
```

Last few line of journal file:

```
' 1:< ::10:: Delta VM: Avail -27 -> 8384734 MB, Used +4 -> 437 MB; RAM: Avail -13 -> 3329 MB, Used +5 -> 528 MB 
' C 07-Sep-2016 12:17:22.868;   1:< Exception in exportToObj() method :: Setting active view is temporarily disabled.
' at RevitCommandListener.RevitCommandListenerService.OpenAndActivate3DView(UIApplication uiApp)
' at RevitCommandListener.RevitCommandListenerService.exportToObj(UIApplication uiApp)
```

Comment: You may want to catch specific Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions to help narrow down the issue.  The Revit API SDK describes 3 potential exceptions with UIDocument.ActiveView: ArgumentNullException, ArgumentException, and InvalidOperation Exception.  It goes on to describe the conditions where you might encounter the exceptions when trying to set the active view.

Comment: in addition to mtumiminello's suggestion, i would like to point out that you should never, ever, catch all exceptions: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-distinguish-redundant-rooms.html#3

Comment: in your note above, do you in fact mean to say that "Note: Modelless dialog activates ***2D*** view without any problem"?

Comment: @JeremyTammik : Modelless dialog activates 3D view but the same code in giving exception with Idling event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the call to change the view out of the Idling event handler. Where else can you put it? Into some method that is called later on, and is not an Idling event handler. One possibility that comes to mind is to implement an external command X that sets the view and call PostCommand in the Idling event handler to launch X at a later point in time. Please let us know whether that works better. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the following thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720839/revit-to-pdf-conversion/)

Comment: your comment has nothing whatsoever to do with this question and is totally out of place here. please desist in future.

Comment: Apologies. Was desperate to find the issue. Will keep that in mind. :)